# Streamlit button inside column: Only one button output displayed at a time

Tags: streamlit

I am not able to create columns with buttons, where all button output is shown simultanously. The below code shows my problem.

```
import streamlit as st

col1, col2 = st.columns(2)

with col1:
    runButton = st.button("Perform calculation 1")
    if runButton:
        st.subheader("1")

with col2:
    runButton = st.button("Perform calculation 2")
    if runButton:
        st.subheader("2")
```

When button1 is clicked, output for button 1 is displayed. But when I then click on button 2, the output from button 1 dissapears.

Does anyone know how to change the code above so that the output from one button remains after the other button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

The [core execution model of Streamlit](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/get-started/main-concepts) is that the entire app reruns when you interact with a widget.

> Every time a user interacts with a widget, your script is re-executed and the output value of that widget is set to the new value during that run.

To prevent your app from rerunning when you click one of the buttons, you can set it up as a form with a submit button, e.g.

```
import streamlit as st

col1, col2 = st.columns(2)

with st.form("calculations"):
    with col1:
        calc_1 = st.checkbox("Calculation 1")
    with col2:
        calc_2 = st.checkbox("Calculation 2")
    submit_button = st.form_submit_button("Complete calculations")

if submit_button:
    if calc_1:
        st.write("1")
    if calc_2:
        st.write("2")
```